# Do photons have six degrees of freedom?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, photons, degrees-of-freedom

Calculations involving pressure and volume relationships of photon gas during the cosmologic expansion of the universe posit an adiabatic cooling process with a heat capacity ration of 4/3.
This ratio would seem to suggest that photons have six degrees of freedom.
However, I am guessing that a photon would have three spatial degrees of freedom and two more for each of the two helicities (polarizations).
I suppose one could even argue that a photon gas has an infinite number of degrees of freedom for each frequency. 
Is there any way anyone could explain this apparent discrepancy?

Answer (score 3):

Photons have two degrees of freedom, the helicity. But they are not an ideal gas with equation of state $$PV = NkT,$$ so the usual derivation of the adiabatic exponent does not apply. You need to use the equation of state $$U = PV$$
which is valid for any ultra-relativistic gas. You can derive it in the same way as the ideal gas law -- by considering collisions with the container -- but remembering to use the ultra-relativistic relationship between energy and momentum, $E = pc$, and $v = c$.

Comment: I have seen following argument used: If L is a ruler expanding with the universe, then $$U\propto\frac{1}{L^4}$$ since energy density decreases with increases in volume (length factor cubed -universe is flat) and since  energy of each photon decreases directly with length factor (redshift). So $$ V\propto L^3\propto (\frac{1}{U^{1/4}})^3\propto \frac{1}{P^{3/4}}$$, since $$P=(1/3) U$$. This implies that $$PV^{4/3}=constant$$. It is as if photon gas (CMB) expands adiabatically with expansion of universe. So if one uses $$\gamma=1+(2/f)$$ then f (deg of freedom) would be equal to 6 for photons.

Comment: I do see now that photons have only two degrees of freedom. From my own limited non-QED viewpoint, photons can not be deflected by fields of other particles (like say an electron deflected in its motion around a charged nucleus) without being created or destroyed. So photons are in one sense stuck in one direction of space on the null-cone of 3+1 space. Of course, photons are deflected by gravity. But this is due to the geometry of space-time rather than a degree of freedom.